# R - Recursion behavior in unlist within lapply

Tags: r, list, lapply

I am working on a custom function that I will need to apply to a set of texts. I have a vector of document names that the function reads in, grabs a piece of metadata and some keywords, and generates a list-of-lists where the outer list is a list of documents and the inner lists each consist of [[1]] metadata (a numeric vector) and [[2]] keywords (a matrix of character elements). I need to convert this to a single unnested list containing both the metadata and the keywords, i.e., if I have 12 documents, this list will have 24 elements.

The example I've provided here is a **lot** simpler than what I'm actually dealing with, but it reproduces the problem I'm having. I mention this only because some seemingly obvious solutions to the toy version probably won't work on the real data, particularly if they rely on changing the input format.

```
doc1 <- c("aa","bb","cccc")
doc2 <- c("abc","dd","eee","ff")
doc3 <- c("bd","qh")

docs <- c(doc1,doc2,doc3)

get_outputs <- function(x) {
current_doc <- as.vector(x)
doc_length <- 1 ##this is dynamic in the real code but not the problem here
input_list <- list(doc_length,current_doc)
unlisted_outputs <- unlist(input_list,recursive=FALSE)
##some more code would go here that operates on unlisted_outputs 
##but this is where the problem occurs
return(unlisted_outputs)
}

lapply(docs,get_outputs)
[[1]]
[1] "1"  "aa"

[[2]]
[1] "1"  "bb"

[[3]]
[1] "1"    "cccc"

[[4]]
[1] "1"   "abc"

[[5]]
[1] "1"  "dd"
```

...etc.

But the output i actually want is what I would get from:

```
get_outputs2 <- function(x) {
current_doc <- as.vector(x)
doc_length <- 1
input_list <- list(doc_length,current_doc)
return(input_list)
}

unlist(lapply(docs,get_outputs2),recursive=FALSE)

[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] "aa"

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
[1] "bb"
```

...etc.

There are reasons why I like that output format, although if I could get  something like:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1
[2] 1
[3] 1
...

[[2]]
[1] "aa"
[2] "bb"
[3] "cccc"
...
```

that would also be fine.

The solution I proposed about outputting list-of-lists and unlisting outside of the function is not my preference because I would like the function to do some other things downstream before returning, but I can't easily do those things on the list-of-lists. Appreciate any thoughts anyone might have.

**Update**: I want to again emphasize that everything up to the step that results in a data structure that looks like input_list can't be altered. I realize that the problem gets a lot easier if the data can be read in more cleanly, as it could in this toy example, but in the actual data it can't, or at least, for the purposes of this question we should assume it can't. I am specifically looking for a way of getting unlist(x,recursive=TRUE) or something very much like it to function inside of lapply the way it does outside of lapply.

Comment: I think you mean to write `docs = list(docs1, docs2, doc3)`, otherwise you entirely lose the split between the three. Anyway, if that's the format, then `library(data.table); rbindlist(lapply(docs, as.data.table), id = "src")` is one way to store it.

Comment: @Frank Not quite what I'm looking for, although I appreciate the effort. It's much more challenging to change the format of anything up to the point where I get the list of lists in the real data than in this toy example.

Comment: @NateF Do you want the simplified structure extracted out from the inital listoflists into a new list or you want that new structure to replace the original structure of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I greatly appreciate your efforts @CPak @Frank @tushaR, but they didn't quite get me what I wanted. I solved my problem with a nested function:

```
get_unlisted_outputs <- function(y){

   get_outputs2 <- function(x) {
     current_doc <- as.vector(x)
     doc_length <- 1
     input_list <- list(doc_length,current_doc)
     return(input_list)
   }

  intermediate_step <- lapply(y,get_outputs2)
  unlisted_outputs <- unlist(intermediate_step,recursive=FALSE)
  return(unlisted_outputs)
  }

get_unlisted_outputs(docs)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the structure of your real data, it's difficult to offer a general solution. Nevertheless, are you saying these outputs are undesirable?

```
list(rep(seq_along(docs), lengths(docs)), unlist(docs))

# [[1]]
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3

# [[2]]
# [1] "aa"   "bb"   "cccc" "abc"  "dd"   "eee"  "ff"   "bd"   "qh"

cbind(rep(seq_along(docs), lengths(docs)), unlist(docs))

     # [,1] [,2]  
 # [1,] "1"  "aa"  
 # [2,] "1"  "bb"  
 # [3,] "1"  "cccc"
 # [4,] "2"  "abc" 
 # [5,] "2"  "dd"  
 # [6,] "2"  "eee" 
 # [7,] "2"  "ff"  
 # [8,] "3"  "bd"  
 # [9,] "3"  "qh"
```

Answer (score 0):

From the question description I am assuming a list with the following structure:

```
l = list(list("doc1",list("meta1","key1")),list("doc2",list("meta2","key2")))

>l

#[[1]]
#[[1]][[1]]
#[1] "doc1"

#[[1]][[2]]
#[[1]][[2]][[1]]
#[1] "meta1"

#[[1]][[2]][[2]]
#[1] "key1"



#[[2]]
#[[2]][[1]]
#[1] "doc2"

#[[2]][[2]]
#[[2]][[2]][[1]]
#[1] "meta2"

#[[2]][[2]][[2]]
#[1] "key2"
```

The following code can get you rid of the nested structure:

```
meta = sapply(
            sapply(
               lapply(l,"[[",2),
            function(t){unlist(t)},simplify = T),
       list,USE.NAMES = F)

>meta
#[[1]]
#[1] "meta1"

#[[2]]
#[1] "key1"

#[[3]]
#[1] "meta2"

#[[4]]
#[1] "key2"
```